# What's "the next big thing"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-origin

[The next big thing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/next-big-thing) is a common set phrase meaning:

> the new rage; the latest fad or trend, esp. in a particular field. - *Flat-panel televisions are the next big thing*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20next%20big%20thing&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20next%20big%20thing%3B%2Cc0) shows that the expression became popular from the early '90s but earlier usages date from the first decades of the 20th century as in:

[The Mid-Pacific Magazine](https://books.google.it/books?id=Hgw6AQAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&dq=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3vYnEn-bXAhVC1RQKHZ47CswQ6AEIJzAA) 1926

> After that, ***the next big thing*** as Lord Northcliffe would say, I want to see the new five ton clock, which was to be erected on the skyscraper of the Colgate Soap Company in New Jersey.

and from [The National Underwriter](https://books.google.it/books?id=SHQXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&dq=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3vYnEn-bXAhVC1RQKHZ47CswQ6AEIMDAB) 1933:

> Why did I take out life insurance? In the first place I was compelled to save through it, and that is one of the big assets of life insurance. ***The next big thing*** is protection.

So, where does this expression come from? Was it a slogan of some early advertising campaign for instance?

What made it popular from the early '90s? Was it the rise of tech devices and their quick evolution?

Comment: Yep, 1890s: https://books.google.com/books?id=e_0SAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA639&dq=%22next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii54TNrObXAhVhr1QKHVVWBNcQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22next%20big%20thing%22&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks that link just takes me to a listing for the Journal of the American Medical Association, there are no page views available. If what you can see is an answer, could you perhaps post it as such with a screenshotted image?

Comment: It takes you to page 639, with "the next big thing" highlighted.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+next+big+thing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20next%20big%20thing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Reading the link provided by @HotLicks and other links from the 19th century, my impression is that those uses are not idiomatic and don't mean the same thing as the set phrase discussed in the question.  Note that the AMA journal article is under the title "Big Things."  '*I asked my friend why he does not take the Journal [...] his reply was as follows: **"It is too full of* big things"**'    ... // So my impression is that *the next "big thing"* in that article is just the "big thing" that literally follows other "big things" in the specific context of the passage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Early stages of 'the next big thing'***

The earliest instance of the character string "the next big thing" that a Google Books search turns up frames the character string as "the next 'big thing'"—that is, it treats "big thing" as the set phrase and uses *next* as a simple modifier. From a [news item](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=DD18690309.1.3&txq=%22the+next+big+thing%22) in the *Richmond [Virginia] Dispatch* (March 9, 1869):

> The last war between the Atlantic trunk lines for the trade for and from common points in the West lasted only ten days, terminating on the 27th day of February. The New York *Tribune* says Vanderbilt won the belt, and makes the Commodore's performance in the premises **the next "big thing"** to his eighty per cent. dividend on New York Central capital shares.

Here, the expression seems to mean nothing more than "the second-most important holding." The meaning of the phrase at this stage bears little relation to the modern idiomatic sense described in user159691's question.

Somewhat closer to the modern meaning is an [advertisement for W.W. Pierce & Co.](http://digitalnewspapers.libraries.psu.edu/Olive/APA/CivilWar/?skin=civilwar&BaseHref=EOB/1869/05/06&EntityId=Ar00402#panel=search&search=0) in the *Erie [Pennsylvania] Observer* (1869) for several farm implements—a plow, a grain drill, and a seed sower. According to the advertisement, after observing that the Mohawk Valley Clipper Plow "hardly needs a recommendation":

> **The next big thing** is the EMPIRE GRAIN DRILL!

which initially sounds like a thoroughly modern use of "the next big thing," until the ad turns to its next implement:

> But **the biggest thing yet** is the newly introduced and novel Machine entitled CAHOON'S BROADCAST SEED SOWER! This is generating great interest all over the country, and is destined to rapidly become the most popular article of its class.

Evidently, although "big thing" has a very modern sense of "big deal" or "popular favorite" in this advertisement, the wording "the next 'big thing'" as used here just means "the next popular favorite in our lineup."

By 1870, "the next big thing" has taken another step forward and begins appearing in the sense of "the next major planned event." From "[Seegers' Ice](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026909/1870-09-07/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22)," in the *Newberry [South Carolina] Herald* (September 7, 1870):

> The chunks of ice for the Herald, came through Messrs. Smiyh & Christian, of this place, who keep champagne on ice, and sudorifics, generally, and who, on this occasion, in their usual gallant style, sent us a bottle of Heidsic, which, with the assistance of the devil, we duly drank to the success of the granite walk, being **the next big thing** now on the tapis of Newberry.

As noted in a [recent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104887/on-tap-in-the-sense-of-coming-up/420958#420958) to an old question about the origin of "on tap," the idiom "on the tapis" means "on the table," "under consideration," or (by extension) "in the offing."

And from an [untitled item](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=THG18751228.1.4&txq=%22the+next+big+thing%22) in the *Terre Haute [Indiana] Evening Gazette* (December 28, 1875):

> The4 New Year's ball, by the Prairie City Lodge, No. 3, at Dowling Hall, will be a big affair.
>
> The ball of the new lodge O. A. U. M., on Friday Evening, is **the next big thing** on the boards.

These instances, where "the next big thing" is roughly equivalent to "the next big event," appear in multiple places in the late 1870s: in [Stroudsburg, Pennsylvania](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026399/1876-12-07/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (December 7, 1876) in connection with a political intrigue; in [Cairo, Illinois](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033413/1877-05-05/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (May 5, 1877), a "baby exposition"; in [Newberry, South Carolina](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026909/1878-03-20/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) again (March 20, 1878), Easter; in Brenham, Texas (July 19, 1878), a "Pomological exhibition"; [Hillsborough, Ohio](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038158/1879-06-19/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (June 19, 1879), a school commencement exercise; and [Memphis, Tennessee](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045160/1880-09-02/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (September 2, 1880), a railroad and steamboat excursion. They take us a considerable distance toward the modern meaning, "the newest fad or breakthrough or popular success," and they continue unabated over the next several decades.

Yet another instance that suggests movement in that direction appears in a [letter by W.P. Howle, M.D.](https://books.google.com/books?id=I_ZGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA639&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVgfyguO_XAhVO22MKHfTXAVoQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&f=false), to the editor of *Journal of the American Medical Association* (April 28, 1894):

> In a friendly chat with one of my medical friends, recently, I asked him why he did not take the *Journal of the American Medical Association*. His reply was a follows: ""It is too full of **big things**." There is some truth in this assertion. The *Journal* is often full of **big things**; my friend claims that the so-called expert and the specialist are allowed too much space in which to air themselves; that it requires too much effort on the part of the country doctor to digest  the "**big things**." He says the country doctor's time is better spent in reading a few practical *truths* than in trying to analyze a lengthy article on "Electro-anesthesia and Frequency of Induction Vibration;" "The Esoteric Beauty of One Hundred and Forty-one Histories and Laparotomies for that Disease under Personal Observation." To the specialist these **big things** are really *big*, but to the average country practitioner they are too utterly too too. ...
>
> The **next "big thing"** to which I call attention, is the nostrum vendor. This dare-devil worries me; every mail brings some of his diabolical literature or some of his infernal stuff, "all free gratis and for nothing." I will treat any doctor in the United States to a plug hat who will show me how to stop this fellow from writing me.

Here the writer seems to be using "big thing" in the somewhat sarcastic way that a person might use "big hoopla" or "big to-do," with the implication that "the next big thing" is to some extent a product of popular gullibility and the public's insatiable desire for novelty.

---

***The earliest thoroughly modern 'next big thing'***

The earliest occurrence I've found of the expression "the next big thing" in what looks to me to be its thoroughly modern sense of "the new rage in a particular field" is from 1910, in the title of a [cartoon by Rube Goldberg](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SFC19101122.2.64.1&txq=%2522the+next+big+thing%2522) from The *San Francisco [California] Call* (November 22, 1910):

> **Aeroboxing the Next Big Thing.**

The cartoon depicts champion boxer Jack Johnson sailing through the sky in boxing gear strapped to an airplane-like conveyance. Evidently the cartoon was inspired by a comment from the prizefighter: "Jack Johnson predicts that the aeroplane will be used in the fighting game." A second very early instance of "the next big thing" in the relevant sense is from [another Rube Goldberg cartoon](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SFC19120920.2.92.1&txq=%2522the+next+big+thing%2522)—this one from the *San Francisco [California] Call* (September 20, 1912):

> **The Automatic Life Is the Next Big Thing.**

The cartoon anticipates automated shoe stores, hat stores, restaurants, barber shops, and hospitals.

Google Books and Elephind searches turned up several other instances from 1912 and very early 1913. From "[What Credit Means to the Farmer](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth331819/m1/5/zoom/?q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&resolution=2&lat=4648.689451946823&lon=1149.7975660787858)," an article on cooperative rural credit associations, in the *Abilene [Texas] Reporter* (January 10, 1912):

> This is **the next big thing** the commercial organizations of the United States are going to tackle—and accomplish. Why shouldn't the organization in your town be among the first to try it out? What's the use of letting some other town get ahead of you?

From [*Mysterious Mr. Sabin*](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/101027328?searchTerm=%22the+next+big+thing%22), serialized in the Molong [New South Wakes] Express (October 19, 1912):

> " That is quite true, Mr, Sabin said. "I admit that there are difficulties, but it seems to me that you have overlooked the crux of the whole matter. I have offered you enough to live on for the rest of your days, without ever returning to Europe. You know very well that you can step off this ship arm in arm with me when we reach Boston, even though your man-of-war be alongside the dock. They could not touch you—you could leave your—pardon me—not too honourable occupation once and for ever. America is nob the country in which one would choose to live, but it has its resources —it can give you big game and charming women. It is not Europe, but it is **the next big thing**. Come, you had better accept my terms!"

From *The International Socialist Review* (December 1912), in an article by Samuel Ball called "[The Next Big Thing](https://books.google.com/books?id=qFNIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA480&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVgfyguO_XAhVO22MKHfTXAVoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&f=false)":

> The phrase, "Life is just one thing after another," rings true. It is even more noticeably true in the activity of the Socialist movement, where **one big thing** follows another in quick succession, each one bigger and closer on the heels of the preceding one. We have not time to rest up from one season of activity till we are fairly plunged into the midst of another.
>
> First it is the city, then the state campaign. We have not time to catch even a "forty winks" until the presidential campaign is upon us, and now before the smoke of battle has fairly cleared away, we look around for **the next big thing** to find that already before we knew it, it has established itself and grown to towering dimensions.
>
> **The next big thing** is the Lyceum. It is already ushered in. As nearly as may be judged, the Lyceum Department has done every thing possible in the way of preparation.

From an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn92053934/1913-01-22/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) in the *Rock Island [Illinois] Argus* (January 22, 1913):

> **The next big thing** in England will be the dethroning of the house of lords.

Other instances in which "the next big thing" describes a wave of popular enthusiasm for a real or imagined innovation or money-making scheme, rather than excitement about a discrete scheduled event involve [buying property along anticipated main transportation lines near Los Angeles](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=LAH19130315.2.82.4&txq=%2522the+next+big+thing%2522) (March 15, 1913), [tree crops](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=FFR19131129.2.18.1&txq=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (November 29, 1913), [chemotherapy](https://books.google.com/books?id=R3EgAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA713&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVgfyguO_XAhVO22MKHfTXAVoQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&f=false) (December 1914), an [expanding copper company](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth198649/m1/9/zoom/?q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&resolution=4&lat=1412.5&lon=2287.5) (February 16, 1917), [funding research to improve U.S. aircraft](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1919-07-20/ed-1/seq-58/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (July 20, 1919), the [Catherine mine](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn96060547/1919-08-09/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22the+next+big+thing%22) (August 9, 1919), [automobiles made of cotton](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth400660/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&resolution=4&lat=4952.068466854829&lon=3046.524916694808) (February 3, 1922), [wireless radio receivers](https://books.google.com/books?id=U502AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA304&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJvqWPxe_XAhVG02MKHR3kDKUQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20next%20big%20thing%22&f=false) (April 24, 1922), and [anonymous authorship](https://books.google.com/books?id=qVRLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22the+next+big+thing%22&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJvqWPxe_XAhVG02MKHR3kDKUQ6AEIQzAF) (1925).

---

***'The next big thing' in 1970s popular music and beyond***

My own memory of the rise of "the next big thing" was in connection with the music industry, where in the early 1970s record companies and the music press were on alert for "the next Dylan," "the next Beatles," etc., and ultimately settled on the more generically appealing "the Next Big Thing"—sometimes rendered in initial caps—for a band, a singer, or an emerging musical genre. That is the seems to be the gist of Sam Sutherland, "[Next Big Thing Fever](https://books.google.com/books?id=eVRLAAAAYAAJ&q=%22the+next+big+thing%22&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQyOzezu_XAhUJ8mMKHe7LA8MQ6AEIPDAF)," in  *High Fidelity* magazine, volume 29 (1979) [combined snippets]:

> American popular music is as much a product of fashion as of art. Now that the recording industry is again embracing rock & roll after its year-long affair with disco, that underlying tension between commerce and artistic expression merits particularly close scrutiny. Against a backdrop of this year's severe sales slump, New Wave-influenced rock has made the transition from grass-roots ugly duckling to commercial swan. Executives who found the rough-and-tumble style laughable at its inception have embraced a new faith, fervently hailing the movement as their salvation. While we agree on aesthetic terms, and commend the trade's more creative producers and a&r folk for their sincere support, the motives fueling many of the conversions are somewhat questionable.
>
> ...
>
> Now the music industry, spurred by radio's new willingness to expose this revitalized rock, is applying the same overkill tactics it did to disco. **The Next Big Thing** is being trumpeted, the bait sweetened by the very cost savings outlined in POP-POURRI last month.

And from a [review of David Bowie's *Let's Dance*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cJpUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the+next+big+thing%22&dq=%22the+next+big+thing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQyOzezu_XAhUJ8mMKHe7LA8MQ6AEIODAE), in *Stereo Review* (1983) [combined snippets]:

> "Let's Dance" is Bowie's first album since I980's "Scary Monsters," and, as with all of his records, there's at least a chance that somewhere in these grooves is **the Next Big Thing**. The surprise is that what's new here is emotion — not the tortured identity crisis of some exile from Mars or the world-weariness of a gigolo but a simple, almost old- fashioned hunger for real love in the real world. The songs on "Let's Dance" work on two levels. First, you can dance to almost everything here.

But whether the music industry's use of "the next big thing" invigorated a usage that had been in continuous since the early 1910s or merely coincided with an older, forgotten tradition, "the next big thing" was a popular expression in the 1910s and 1920s, with essentially the same meaning that it has now. And if any one person deserves credit for popularizing the expression in the 1910s, that person is the great U.S. cartoonist Rube Goldberg, who accounts for two of the earliest definite modern-style instances of "the next big thing" that I found in my Elephind newspaper database and Google Books database searches—dating to 1910 and 1912.

Answer (score 3):

Not to split hairs, and perhaps expectably, the story of the 'next big thing' starts with the story of the 'big thing'. The bare bones of this peculiarly US linguitic tale appear in *OED*:

> **big thing**  *n. colloq.* (orig. U.S.) something important, impressive, or popular; (esp. in early use) *spec[ifically]* ***a promising or potentially profitable scheme, opportunity***, etc.; cf. *next big thing*....
>
> [bold emphasis mine]

The cross-referenced 'next big thing', as defined in *OED*, is

> the latest popular sensation; the newest trend in a particular field.

So, the set phrase 'next big thing' refines and focuses the sense of the set phrase 'big thing'. That refinement may be detected in a sequence of articles about the Boise gold rush of 1862-1864 printed in the [*Santa Cruz Weekly Sentinel*](https://www.newspapers.com/image/55449559/?terms=%22next%2Bbig%2Bthing%22) (Santa Cruz, California, 30 Jul 1864, paywalled). The first of the articles was picked up from the "*Ter. [?] Enterprise*", and notes the 'big thing' antecedent to the 'next big thing' mentioned later:

> *Old Without Knowing It*. In our rambles about the city yesterday, it occurred to us that there were hundreds of men on the Pacific Coast who have grown old without being aware of the fact...[he] did not realize that he had grown old in gold hunting — doubtless it appeared to him but a very short time since he started out in pursuit of the "big thing" which, although it had heretofore eluded him, must soon fall into his hands, ....

After several intervening articles, the phrase is picked up in a short paragraph of filler material:

> The return tide from Boise has begun. Interior papers mention several parties who have come back to California, satisfied — until the next "big thing" looms up in the distance.

In the 1861 *The Prince's Visit: a Humorous Description of the Tour of His Royal Highness, the Prince of Wales, Through the United States of America, in 1860*, by R.J. de Cordova, some lines of doggerel are later glossed with the author's conception of the meaning of 'big thing'. The author's gloss of the phrase, although obviously related to it, is a bigger and broader thing than the narrower gloss provided by *OED*:

> And, when the Mayor said that he hoped the reception
>   Had not fallen short of His Grace's conception
>   Of what New-York would do to let it be seen
>   How greatly she honored the Son of the Queen,
>   The Duke, gratified,
>   In these words replied:
>   I'm, indeed, at a loss
>   To express, old Hoss,
>   The feelings that now round my old heart cling.
>   We are grateful, indeed. 'T was a very **big thing**.
>
> [op cit. p 62](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hwqtw1;view=1up;seq=76), bold emphasis mine
>
> ....
>
> Anything extraordinary is alluded to as "a big thing." I have heard the term applied to a sermon, a glass of rare wine, a lady's fan made of expensive material, a heavy show of rain or a storm, an elegant ring, **a commercial enterprise or speculative operation**, &c.
>
> [op cit. p 89](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hwqtw1;view=1up;seq=111), bold emphasis mine.

An examination of historical phrase continuity, corroborated by the *OED* lexical glosses of the two phrases, shows the sense of 'next big thing' resonates the common semantic elements of the 'big thing', that is, popularity and profitability, throughout its further refinement, development and ultimate quasi-separation as a set phrase from the 'big thing'.

Picking up the phrase from 1863, however, a year earlier than the 1864 use quoted above, it can be seen the core sense of 'profitable and popular' is already in play in the 'next big thing':

> **Fistic and Other Sports in Nevada**
>   ....
>   Our **next big thing** is the fight to come off between McGrath...and Tom Daley....
>
> [*New York Clipper*, 17 October 1863](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=NYC18631017.2.22&txq=%22next%20big%20thing%22).

Here, the phrase 'next big thing' is a *non sequitur* in that it doesn't follow any use of 'big thing', although it does follow a description of an earlier fight that was, presumably, a 'big thing'. It is apparent the promoter expects the sense of 'popular and profitable' will be understood from the phrase 'big thing'.

---

Taking your questions in order:

1. So, where does this expression come from?

The sense of the set phrase 'next big thing' arose as a more or less natural extension of predictive use of the set phrase 'big thing'.

Of the set phrase 'big thing', and despite the observations being out of scope for your question, I will mention that my research revealed some tantalizing facts and suggestive connections with later use of 'next big thing'.

For examples:

- Use of the phrase 'big thing' seems to have been primarily US throughout its history.
- Such use was scarce prior to 1810.
- Between the years 1001 (chosen to reduce noise in the data from works 'published' in year 1000) and 1863, there are 1263 hits in the [*HathiTrust*](https://www.hathitrust.org/) digital corpus.
- 1185 of the 1263 hits appear between 1810 and 1863.
- Between 1863 and 1869, 1266 additional hits appear in that corpus.
- A cursory check of the hits between 1863 and 1869 suggests that many of the additional hits come from song lyrics.

The facts mentioned suggest, overall, that a marked increase in the use of 'big thing' is associated with the US civil war.

2. Was it a slogan of some early advertising campaign for instance?

If the use of 'next big thing' was sloganistic, I did not detect that influence in the data I looked at.

3. What made it popular from the early '90s? Was it the rise of tech devices and their quick evolution?

Speculation follows:

In line with my observation that the earlier marked increase in use of 'big thing' was associated with the US civil war, and a hypothesis that the observed increase of such use reflects the US re-ordering and redistribution of capital wealth caused by that war, I suggest that the later marked increase in use of 'next big thing' (supposing that the increase shown in Ngrams is not simply an artifact of patchy, insufficient data), is similarly associated with an ongoing underground civil war occasioned by another radical re-ordering and redistribution of US capital wealth, as reflected by the concurrent sharp rise in income inequality in the US.

Song lyrics, I observe in this context, often express, through coded messaging, the essence of national popular struggles.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/next_big_thing states that the origin of the phrase was used in Sounds during the 1970's. By https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/skinsman, we can see that "Sounds" refers to music. Therefore, this phrase most likely was used in the 1970's to mean a musician that would most likely become successful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Druggists Circular - Volume 58 - Page 713
>
> https://books.google.com/books?id=R3EgAQAAMAAJ 1914 - ‎Read - ‎More
> editions
>
> Now it is found that the organism which causes hydrophobia is
> an animal parasite very similar to the malaria germ, and with this
> recent knowledge it seems more than probable that **the next big thing**
> in chemo-therapy will be in this direction. Whether quinine will be
> the direct agent or whether it is to be some chemical combination such
> as "606," is hard to anticipate, but such results as may be
> accomplished will serve to elevate and magnify the science and have a
> decided influence ...
>
> The Merck Report - Volume 24 - Page 63
>
> https://books.google.com/books?id=kDhHAQAAMAAJ 1915 - ‎Read - ‎More
> editions
>
> In addition to serums, **the next big thing** in pharmacy or to
> influence pharmacy will no doubt be chemo-therapy, recently revived
> with such success by Professor Ehrlich. This treatment depends on new
> chemical compounds which may be injected into the human body without
> damage to the cells or tissues to destroy certain poisonous germs
> causing disease through entrance to the blood. The pioneer work in
> this line was really accomplished when quinine was found to be a
> specific ...

So apparently the phrase was first used in medicine.